# Execute asynchronous processes one after another

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 5000 elements, I am executing it in below manner

```
var arr = [..] // 5000 elements array
split = 10;
arr.split(split);
function asyncForLoop(){
   // It takes advantage of Web workers and execute for loop
}
var pending = new Array(split), data = [];
for(var i = 0, l = 4; i++){
   (function(a){
       data[i] = new asyncForLoop(a, function(){

       });
   })(arr[i]);
   pending.shift();
}
```

This is the way I am executing the for loop. 
 1. I am splitting an array into 10 slices
 2. Creating 4 asynchronous processes to execute first four slices of for loop.
Here is my question
 3. I want to implement a mechanism where 4 asynchronous processes will be running on first four array slices, whoever completed first in the race will pick the 5th item, next will pick the 6th item. It means pick the item which is pending still.

Here I am facing a challenge that if two processes complete on same time, both will execute the same pending item as the status will be pending at that time.

Could you please give me an idea of implementing this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semaphore to protect your pending list. Only one process can have the semaphore at any one time, so the process holding the semaphore can safely touch the pending list.

Comment: Javascript webworkers don't have semaphores. There is no traditionally shared data between threads, everything is message based.

Comment: But you can implement a message-based semaphore, can't you? I don't know much about web workers, but I assume that they can be made to wait for a message to be posted.

Comment: I assume, even if two processes completed on same time, as JS executes  one after another, I don't think it would not be an issue? am I correct?

Comment: If you code all of your processes to wait on your semaphore mechanism, there will be no problem. --Edit: I see that there are a few posts on SO when I google 'web worker semaphore'. Hopefully one of those can give you an idea of the details.